# Gsuite SAML integration with ASP.net Application

Tags: asp.net, saml, google-workspace

I am developing ASP.Net web application, and we want to integrate it with GSuite using SAML,
Gsuite will have all user information, 
We have created SAML application in GSuite, and We want our asp.net to redirect to Google for authentication.
Is there any Sample code in .net

Thanks